# Use all rows from the table returned by JDBC request

Tags: loops, jdbc, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I use JDBC request for selecting users who log in to the application. The results return correctly but I noticed that HTTP Sampler uses only the first result from the table.
I use also ForEach Controller to avoid getting the column name as a result but don't think that it is related to the issue.
[image]

The table contains a few results and I want to use them all one by one for each new log-in.
[image]

Comment: Why you have ForEach inside Loop Controller? why not only ForEach?

Comment: Sorry it's not a suitable screenshot but all other tests don't have a Loop controller and it doesn't affect the result yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined "Variable Names" under JDBC Request sampler? It should be done like this:

[image]

This way you will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
businessId_#=number of rows 
businessId_1=value from 1st row
businessId_2=value frmo 2nd row
```

and this way you will be able to iterate them using ForEach Controller

More information:

- [JDBC Request sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)

Comment: Yes, I've defined "Variable Names". I use a Debug sampler and here I see the correct number of values and returned values as well